# Let $f$ be a function with a continuous derivative. Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}n^2\phi'(nx)f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Question: Let $\phi(x)=\frac{15}{16}(x^2-1)^2$ for $|x|<1$ and zero otherwise. Let $f$ be a function with a continuous derivative. Find the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}n^2\phi'(nx)f(x)dx$$
This question is in the context of positive summation kernels. Let's get the easy stuff out of the way. Clearly,
$$n^2\phi'(nx)=\frac{15xn^3}{4}(n^2x^2-1)$$
Clearly, this is not a positive summation kernel, as by inspection of its graph, $n^2\phi'(nx)<0$ on $0<x<1$, so I'm not sure how to proceed. Ideally I would want to show its a positive summation kernel, then use $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}K_n(s)f(s)ds=f(0)$, but this seems out of the question.

Help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Where does integration by parts lead you?

Comment: Substituting $u=nx$ and integrating by parts gives you
$$ n^2\int_{-1}^1\varphi'(nx)f(x)dx=-\int_{-1}^1\varphi(u)f'(u/n)du. $$
Can you continue frome here ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien Can we just safely apply the limit in this case to get $-f'(0)$?

Comment: @William You need to use a theorem to do that, like the dominated convergence theorem.